# NameError: name 'gethostname' is not defined

Tags: python

```
host = gethostbyname(gethostname())
NameError: name 'gethostbyname' is not defined
```

I need some help,  can't figure out what's amiss

Here is the code:

```
conn = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.ntohs(3)) host = gethostbyname(gethostname()) conn.bind((host, 80)).
```

I am trying my hands on a simple packet sniffer in Python.

Comment: here is the code: conn = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.ntohs(3))
    host = gethostbyname(gethostname())
    conn.bind((host, 80)).    Trying my hands on a simple packet sniffer in python. Am a newbie

Comment: So, have you defined that function?

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: Where is `gethostbyname()` defined?

Answer (score 2):

You have to firstly import the [`socket.gethostbyname`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.gethostbyname) function as:

```
from socket import gethostbyname
```

Then your code